# ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined(React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have this error ReferenceError: Highcharts is not defined, I am stuck with this error for a couple of days now, can you help me.

I have Dashboard and Chart files, importing Chart components to the dashboard.

I tried to create the chart component on a separate react project, and it's just working fine.

But when I try to integrate the Chart component into my main project it shows the reference error.
[error message image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1g45.png)

https://github.com/wilmer090/dashboard/tree/feature-charts or
'.[Please see the code of components here](https://jsfiddle.net/ctrlC/u05v8r6m/6/)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Highcharts, { Pointer } from 'highcharts'
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official-fix'
import {Typography} from '@material-ui/core'
import Modal from './components/Modal'




const thirdSetSample = [{...},{...}...]
const sample = thirdSetSample.reduce((accu, curr) => {
  const date = new Date(curr.date_created);
  if (!accu[date]) {
    accu[date] = [];
  }
  accu[date].push(curr);
  return accu;
}, {});


const arr = Object.keys(sample).map((time) => {
  return {
    x:time,
    y: sample[time].length
  };
});

console.log('arr',arr)



const Chart = () =>{
  
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
  
  function handleOpenModal(time, arrayTableValue){
    let props = {}
    const dateTimeToString = time.toString()

    arrayTableValue.forEach(item => item.date_created  = new Date(item.date_created).toString())
  

    const filterForModalTable = arrayTableValue.filter(item => item.date_created == time)
    console.log('updated value',filterForModalTable)
  
    setIsModalOpen(isModalOpen => !isModalOpen)
    props = {...props, time:time, value:thirdSetSample}
  }


  const options = {  
    chart:{
      type:'spline'
    },
    title:{
      text: 'Articles Published'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime' //ensures that xAxis is treated as datetime values
    },
    yAxis: {
      title:{
        text: 'Articles'
      }
    },
    plotOptions:{
      series:{
        cursor: 'Pointer',
        point:{
          events:{
            click: function(){
              handleOpenModal(this.x, thirdSetSample)
              // alert("Category: "  + " Articles: " + this.y)
              //alert(JSON.stringify(filterForModalTable))
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      formatter: function() {
          return '<b>'+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 0) + ' Article' +'</b><br/>'+ Highcharts.dateFormat('%y-%m-%d %l:%M:%P', this.x,true);
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled:false
    },
    series: [{
    
      // number of articles published example
      data: (function(){
          return arr.map(item =>{
            return {x: new Date(item.x), y: item.y}
          })
      }()),
      pointInterval: 3600000,    
    }]
    }

  return(
    <>
      <Typography variant="h1">Chart Sample</Typography>
      <Modal isModalOpen={isModalOpen}/>
    
      <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={options} />
  
    </>
  )
}

export default Chart
```

Comment: Can you share the exact error message?

Comment: I've added the link above for the error message

Comment: Are you sure you installed HighCharts properly? Can I see your package.json?

Comment: sure, here you go https://jsfiddle.net/ctrlC/u05v8r6m/8/

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to create the chart component on a separate react project, and
> it's just working fine.

> But when I try to integrate the Chart component into my main project it shows the reference error.

Highchart may not be installed in your main project. Even if you have it installed, it could not be accessed by your project.
Verify this by console logging in dev-tool for highchart `window.Highcharts`.

If you get `undefined` you need to added/attach highchart to window object.

```
import Highcharts from "highcharts";

window.Highcharts = Highcharts;
```

if you have dependency on other functionality of highchats like drill down you should also import them into your main project.

```
// Do this before assigning Highchat to window

require("highcharts/modules/heatmap")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/sunburst")(Highcharts);
const Drilldown = require("highcharts/modules/drilldown");

if (Drilldown) {
  Drilldown(Highcharts);
}
require("highcharts/modules/map")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/highcharts-more")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/solid-gauge")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/funnel")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/bullet")(Highcharts);
require("highcharts/modules/treemap")(Highcharts);
```